# How to call void foo(int (&)[]) {} in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading

```
void f1(int (&)[8])
{}

void f2(int (&)[])
{}

int main()
{
    int a[8];

    f1(a); // OK

    f2(/* What should I put here? */); // ???

    return 0;
}
```

**How do I call f2?**

PS: void f2(int (&)[]) {} is legal under VC++ 2012.

consider the following:

```
template<class T>
struct A
{};

template<class T>
struct A<T[]>
{};

template<class T, size_t size>
struct A<T[size]>
{};
```

Comment: if the dimension is unknown I'm lost as to why you simply don't specify `void f2(int a[])`.

Comment: My intent is to call f2 with an array of any size while overloading functions existing. e.g. int b[7]; f2(b);

Comment: @xmllmx Then how about `template <size_t N> void f(int (&)[N]) { }`?

Comment: @hvd, your solution is identical to f1.

Comment: @xmllmx The template function won't be picked when a non-template overload offers an exact match. You can have a non-template and a template overload with the same name, there won't be any ambiguity.

Comment: template<class T>
struct A
{};

template<class T>
struct A<T[]>
{};

template<class T, size_t size>
struct A<T[size]>
{};

Comment: @xmllmx I'm not seeing the relevance of that, sorry. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @hvd, I want to say that T[] and T[size] are diffrent types, and the former is more general when overloading.

Comment: @xmllmx Yes, I know they are different types, but that doesn't change the fact that a template function can be called for an array of any size, without specifying the size, does it?

Comment: I think the answer is: 8.3.5/8: If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form "pointer to array of unknown bound of T" or "reference to array of unknown bound of T," the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ has an explicit rule that disallows references or pointers to arrays without bounds as parameters (but those are otherwise valid types). The following would be a valid argument to such a parameter

```
extern int arg[];
```

Note that you cannot use an array with a size. C++ does not have the type compatibility concept. C has, and makes an array type without size compatible to the corresponding array type with a size. In C++, the typesystem is stricter, types have linkage and prototypeless function types do not exist, so type compatibility is not a real need, so C++ dropped it.

Comment: 8.3.5/8: If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form "pointer to array of unknown bound of T" or "reference to array of unknown bound of T," the program is ill-formed.

Comment: I just realised: C++ does not have C's notion of compatible type, so even if `f(int(&)[])` were valid, you wouldn't be able to call it with an `int[10]` lvalue, because `int[10]` and `int[]` are different types. In that light, a parameter of type `int(&)[]`, if it were valid, would be pretty much useless.

Comment: @hvd i was about to write the same :-)

Answer (score 5):

"f2" shouldn't compile in the first place. You can only omit the size of an array parameter if the [] is the first level of indirection, so to speak, in which case it's actually not an array but a pointer. In this case, the first level of indirection is the &, so you can't omit the size in the [].

Comment: void f2(int (&)[]){} is a legal function. So I just wonder how to call it.

Comment: @xmllmx It's not a legal function. I tried compiling it and got: "error C2265: 'abstract declarator' : reference to a zero-sized array is illegal".

Comment: @CharlesBailey There is no technical reason why it wouldn't be possible, and in C, you *can* have `int(*)[]`. But compilers do seem to agree that C++ does not allow pointers or references to incomplete array types.

Comment: @user1610015, void f2(int (&)[]){} is legal under VC++ 2012. I didn't test it under other compilers.

Comment: @xmllmx Well I tested with VC++ 2010. I guess they differ in this respect then.

Comment: @xmllmx And if you can compile it, I'd guess you can call f2 just like f1, but with an array of any size.